# how lo call json column on javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

My JSON data:

```
[{"day0":"0","day1":"0","day2":"2","day3":"1","day4":"1"}]
```

I have tried this and it works for me:

```
var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);

data.setValue(0, 1,Respuesta[0].day0);
data.setValue(1, 1,Respuesta[0].day1);
data.setValue(2, 1,Respuesta[0].day2);
data.setValue(3, 1,Respuesta[0].day3);
data.setValue(4, 1,Respuesta[0].day4);
```

but I need to do it on loop

```
var column = ["day0", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day5", "day6", "day7", "day8", "day9", "day10", "day11", "day12", "day13", "day14", "day15"];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  data.setValue(i, 1,Respuesta[0].column[i]);
}
```

I think I have a problem on this `column[i]`. Please could you help me with that?

Comment: Change `Respuesta[0].column[i]` to `Respuesta[0][column[i]]`.

Comment: Also don't call your string with JSON "`JSON`". It shadows the JSON object. (If you give it another name you can also use `JSON.parse()` instead of `jQuery.parseJSON()` and then you can get rid of jQuery if that's the only thing you use it for.)